# Content of estimate in meta-analysis

Tags: r, meta-analysis

I am currently working on a meta-analysis of studies on a certain protein marker (let's say X) in serum and plasma of patients. Since studies often reported a median with range instead of a mean with SD, I decided to use the 'quantile estimation' method of McGrath *et al* (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metamedian/metamedian.pdf) by using the metamedian package in R, which returns an object of class rma.uni (for the metafor package in R). I have only one sample per study (a median of the serum level of protein X in patients), and the metamedian package would give me therefore according to the documentation above the pooled median of all studies.

However, in the corresponding paper, authors describe that they estimate sampling variance of effect size for all studies and then meta-analyze it using the inverse variance method (McGrath, S, Sohn, H, Steele, R, Benedetti, A. Meta‐analysis of the difference of medians. Biometrical Journal. 2020; 62: 69– 98. https://doi.org/10.1002/bimj.201900036).

Thus, when I use the metamedian package in R and it gives me an 'estimate' with corresponding SE, z-val and p-val (see image), does it return me the pooled median or does it calculate some kind of effect size?

Thanks in advance.

[image: the results of the random-effect meta-analysis]

Comment: When you distinguish between effect size and pooled median just what are you trying to distinguish here? Are you using effect size in a restricted sense approximately equal to Cohen d or Hedges g

Comment: That's exactly what is unclear to me - in this analysis, I do not use a measure which differentiates between two groups (so no patient vs control), it is just one sample of patients and their (often median) values. Which is why it would make more sense to me that the estimate outcome would be a pooled median. I simply do not have a comparison group here. However, the authors of the paper above do describe that they  'estimate sampling variance of effect size for all studies'. According to the documentation of the metamedian package, I could apply QE to one-sample studies, so that should be ok

Comment: The term 'effect size' does not automatically imply a particular measure, although a lot of people do use the term to refer especially to standardized mean differences. But if you use a bunch of medians as input to `rma()`, then the estimate is also a median (or to be precise, if you fit a RE model, it's the estimated average median).

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang! I think this answers my question.